# DATEDIFF IN ACTIVE RECORD IN CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use active record for get some record, and I use datediff fuction for get difference between two dates. This is the active record

```
$this->db->select('a.ID, a.PREFIX,
                   a.SERIAL_NUMBER, a.EOR_NUMBER,
                   a.IN_DATE, a.OUT_DATE, 
                   DATEDIFF(OUT_DATE,IN_DATE ) + 1 AS TOTAL_DATE, a.BALANCE, a.REMARKS, a.NO_EOR');
$this->db->from($this->table . ' as a');
```

But the query was produced like this :

```
SELECT `a`.`ID`, 
   `a`.`PREFIX`, `a`.`SERIAL_NUMBER`, 
   `a`.`EOR_NUMBER`, `a`.`IN_DATE`, 
   `a`.`OUT_DATE`, DATEDIFF(OUT_DATE, `IN_DATE ) + 1` AS `TOTAL_DATE`, 
   `a`.`BALANCE`, `a`.`REMARKS`, 
   `a`.`NO_EOR` FROM 
`tb_fin_storage` as `a`
```

query was wrong in **DATEDIFF(OUT_DATE, `IN_DATE ) + 1` AS `TOTAL_DATE`**, and I can see that the backthick was produced by AR is wrong. Any solution is so appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have back ticks around `IN_DATE ) + 1` that's not syntactically correct

Comment: Had a try with `DATEDIFF(**a**.OUT_DATE, **a**.IN_DATE ) + 1 AS TOTAL_DATE` ?

Comment: @ jeff, that`s the problem

Comment: @zimmi, yes I Had, and not working.

Answer (score 1):

You cando this:

```
 $this->db->select('a.ID, a.PREFIX,
               a.SERIAL_NUMBER, a.EOR_NUMBER,
               a.IN_DATE, a.OUT_DATE, 
               DATEDIFF(OUT_DATE,IN_DATE ) + 1 AS TOTAL_DATE, a.BALANCE, a.REMARKS, a.NO_EOR', false);
```

(add false at the end, it will turn off escaping)

Documentation: $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement.